# C# / VB multiple file references at once

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, msbuild

I have a bunch of files which I use over most of my projects.
To keep the distribution easy, I do not build a DLL but add the files as reference files to my project to generate one EXE.
Is there an easy way to bundle this files (20-30) as one single refernce? I could add all files manually or just copy the reference section of an existing project file, but is there a more elegant way?
Some of the files do not have dependencies (I call them atomic), others depends on each other. So I typically have 2 folders on the project explorer with atomic and dependents with always the same files.

I hope my question is clear. I could also add a post-build merger to add the DLL, but when it comes to fuscation or other stuff the all-in-one concept is more robust.

Regards Martin

See above - add 30 files at one shot to my project

Comment: so you want to reference those sourcecode-files from different projects, right?

Comment: You really ought to build a DLL and then create a NuGet package.

Comment: Yes, this is some sort of „my own framework“. Building a package - well the files are very dynamic and are updated very often …

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, then [Shared Project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/) is exactly what you need. You put your common source code files in a separate .shproj project. Then you add a reference to the shared project from your main EXE project. The files become a part of the main project and only a single EXE will be compiled.

Comment: Thx, this looks like the missing thing for me, I will try that 

Comment: It seems that adding an existing file always creates a copy and does not add a reference, as I can not select "add as reference" ... So this is not the ideal way but a way anyhow

Comment: There seem to be some bugs in the IDE as I could select "Add as reference" for the 1st add, but afterwords it did not work out. Editing the project file manually is working, so this way ...